# On the complex matrix equation $AX-XA=B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, jordan-normal-form

I want to show that there exists solution to the matrix equation $AX-XA=B$ if and only if
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
A&0\\
0&A
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
A&B\\
0&A
\end{pmatrix}
$$
are similar, where all matrices ($A,B,X$) are complex and $A,B$ are $n\times n$.

The sufficiency is easy to show, while I could only manage to show the necessity in some special cases. I also noticed that this is in fact a special case of a much more general Roth's theorem, however I am more interested in this particular question (i.e. how is this equation special). Is there a proof to show the necessity without (over) generalizing?

Comment: What is Roth's theorem?

Comment: @copper.hat   see  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266428979_Roth%27s_Removal_Rule_and_the_Rational_Canonical_Form

Comment: If one wants to prove Roth's the by considering the eigen-structure of the block matrices, the special case is no easier than the general case. If $A$ has two Jordan blocks $J_1$ and $J_2$, one has to deal with a submatrix of the form $\pmatrix{J_1&\ast\\ 0&J_2}$. The situation is the same in the general case. A matrix-theoretic case for the general case is actually quite straightforward. People give long proofs in the literature only because they want coordinate-free proofs or they don't want an algebraic closure.

Comment: Also, I don't think the general case is an over-generalisation. I actually believe that the general case is more natural than the special case, and people encounter the general case more often than the special one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(I never know which one is necessity and which one is sufficiency, so I'm doing both)*

If $AX-XA=B$, then
$$
\begin{bmatrix}I&X\\0&I\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}A&0\\0&A\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}I&X\\0&I\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}I&-X\\0&I\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}A&0\\0&A\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}I&X\\0&I\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\0&A\end{bmatrix}.
$$
$$
\ 
$$

Conversely, suppose that $\begin{bmatrix}A&0\\0&A\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\0&A\end{bmatrix}$ are similar. Then there exists $\begin{bmatrix}P&Q\\R&S\end{bmatrix}$, invertible, with
$$
\begin{bmatrix}P&Q\\R&S\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}A&0\\0&A\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\0&A\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}P&Q\\R&S\end{bmatrix}.
$$
This gives us
$$\tag1
AP-PA=-BR,
$$
$$\tag2
AQ-QA=-BS,
$$
and
$$\tag3
RA=AR,\qquad SA=AS.
$$
Now,

- if $R$ is invertible, by $(1)$ we can take $X=-PR^{-1}$ (note that $R^{-1}$ commutes with $A$ by $(3)$);
- similarly, if $S$ is invertible by $(2)$ we can take $X=-QS^{-1}$;
- if $R+S$ is invertible, adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ we see that we can take $X=-(P+Q)(R+S)^{-1}$;
- and if $R-S$ is invertible, subtracting $(2)$ from $(1)$ we see that we can take $X=-(P-Q)(R-S)^{-1}$.

In summary, if at least one of $R,S,R+S,R-S$ is invertible, we are done.

At this stage I was convinced that the invertibility of $\begin{bmatrix} P&Q\\ R&S\end{bmatrix}$ would force at least one of $R,S,R+S,R-S$ to be invertible. But I haven't found an argument yet. A few attempts looking for counterexamples when none of $R,S,R+S,R-S$ is invertible did not bear fruit, because the examples I had in hand forced $A$ and $B$ to be trivial; this could be just a feature of my choice of examples, though, as naturally I was working with rather small matrices.